# LTspice-RIAA-simulation not working out

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, ltspice, compensation

I'm trying to simulate a RIAA-phonograph-preamp since I want to build a phono-preamp. I've built everything according to the data provided by LT for the [LT1115](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt1115fa.pdf). But my simulation seems to not be working properly, since my output is not compensating at all. Here is my [circuit](https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/3365664/Low-Noise.asc%5B!%5BCiru%5D%5B1%5D%5D%5B1%5D).
Thanks in advance
[image: Circuit according to LT1115 datasheet]
[image: Simulation]
Vinyl is my input in the filter circuit, and V(n009) my output of the circuit.

Comment: What is an "RIAA-phonograph-preamp"?

Comment: A Preamplifier which also compensates for the RIAA-Curve with which vinyls are recorded

Comment: The output of vinyl is in blue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization#/media/File:RIAA-EQ-Curve_rec_play.svg

Comment: My output of the vinyl is in green, as mentioned in my question and labeled in the picture

Comment: Your input frequency response is wrong way up! As a result the output has double the response of the RIAA curve.

Comment: As a side comment: I would recommend that you take a look at the Burr-Brown series of op-amps; the OPA1655 datasheet actually shows a single op-amp RIAA preamp in the "Typical Application" section.  The OPA1611/1612 has lower distortion, although also much lower input impedance figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output "vinyl" mimics the gain plot of the preamplifier. You need to flip things around so "vinyl" has a lower output at low frequencies and a higher output at high frequencies which is the dotted blue line in the graph below.

From Wikipedia on [RIAA equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIAA_equalization):
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I copied the entire signal part from another project, and somehow it must have been inverted (i have no idea how that happened). Now i'm getting the right thing

Answer (score 1):

I remember old vinyl pop-click, pop-click records.
The same curve appears at
https://sound-au.com/project06.htm .
[image: RIAA EQ]

Comment: But shouldn't my output be just a straight, because i am compensating my input (which is the output of the Vinyl, so a RIAA-Curve)?

Comment: Most EQ curves use a straight flat input frequency response and the EQ is shown with the amounts and frequencies at the output.